# Generating loopback models after generating looback-angular-services?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I've generated angular services for my database using loopback-lb-services and now I want to make some changes in my database.

So i want to know how can i change it. Because i've read that after changing the tables the lb-services will get drop.

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `lb-ng` again to get the updates. You can automate this using a build system like gulp (see https://github.com/strongloop/gulp-loopback-sdk-angular).

Comment: Also as a best-practice I'd like to advise that you check-in your generated services file if you don't do so already. I didn't check-in my lb-services file initially as I would let the grunt or gulp pipeline generate it for me everytime ... BUT later on I started checking it in as part of the source-code because it really helped me learn about the minor tweaks loopback generator was making along the way on my behalf and that learning is "worth it" in the long run when you need to take a look back and figure out what happened. Just my 2 cts.